# 24 hour access at general aviation airport

Tags: general-aviation, usa, airport-operations

I was doing a night flight with my kids and one had to go to the bathroom.  I was happy that when I landing at an airport (KVLA) and they had a door code so I could get to the bathroom.  Is there a list anywhere of small GA airports that you can get access to the bathrooms 24 hours a day?

If not, what is the best way to make one?

Comment: We use water bottle for boys and diaper for girls when we go on a trip.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! If you're asking if GA airports are typically open 24x7, we already have [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/29456/62). If you're asking more specifically about how to find airports that have toilets available 24x7 that's unlikely to be something we can answer here. That could change from day to day, especially given the changing COVID situation and restrictions in different parts of the US. The best way to find out if an airport has a specific service available is usually to just call the FBO there.

Comment: At night, once the airport is closed, they all have 24X7 access to toileting facilities as long as there is no landing restrictions. It is the big green latrine that runs alongside the runway.   While I appreciate the convenience that a bathroom in the FOB might afford, with the right amount of lighting (or lack thereof), I am not above assisting the airfield in its irrigation. Fertilization, on the other hand, is a different story. Stick to Class D and fuel available airfields. They are your best bet for an accessible FBO or pilot shack.

Comment: @DeanF. Getting arrested for Indecent Exposure can get you put on the sex offender registry in some places in the US. Suggesting that public urination is okay is irresponsible.

Comment: @nick012000: Way out by the runway is hardly public.

Comment: @nick012000 - You are absolutely right. Public urination is wrong. You should not urinate in a crowd. But, there is a huge difference between relieving yourself in a few acres of grassy area a half mile away from the closest building and peeing on the building itself. I did say at night after closing after all. Have you never gone camping, fishing, hunting, farming, ranching, off-roading, etc. All these activities occasionally include outdoor peeing. Also, before 6 and after 60, you are going to have to make peeing a priority. And, public urination is a citation, not an arrest in most places.

Comment: @nick012000 - Now, peeing in a stadium men’s room during the post season. That’s public urination. . But, on a serious note, the OP was asking about his kids. Out of all the police officers I know, not one of them is going to write a citation, arrest, or register a child as a sex offender for having to pee. Most of them are parents. And, most parents have had the experience of pulling onto the shoulder of the highway because Little Johnny could not hold it any longer. Eventually, it will get to the point that Big John can’t hold it either. If they are lucky enough to reach that age.

Comment: This devolved fairly quickly.  But anyway, Thank you for your response @Pondlife.  If I would have know that my kid was going to say she needed to go to the bathroom before we left then I would have called. But alas, she is 6.  It would be great to be able to plan rest stops over a 3 hour flight without having to call that many FBOs.

Comment: @Steven You're welcome, and it's a completely reasonable question. I just don't think there's a good, reliable answer.

Answer (score 2):

As someone already commented, creating and maintaining such a list would be difficult, considering there are over 5,000 FBOs in the US alone. Proper flight planning is the best course of action if you know you are flying off-hours. Identify potential bathroom stops along your route, call the FBOs at those airports and ask.